# How to set multiple filters for MapBox?

Tags: android, filter, expression, mapbox

I can set one filter:

```
myLayer.setFilter(eq(get("level"), 1));
```

But how do I set multiple ones?I overwrite the first one when doing:

```
myLayer.setFilter(eq(get("level"), 1));
myLayer.setFilter(eq(get("id"), 123));
```

I don't know how to create a complex Expression.

Answer (score 0):

They can be combined with Expression.all(...)

```
 myLayer.setFilter(
            Expression.all(
                    eq(geometryType(), "Polygon"),
                    eq(get("level"), 1),
                    eq(get("id"), 123)
            )
    );
```

See the "mapbox android demo" *CreateHotspotsActivity*:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo